# API search and site search works different

Tags: api, soundcloud

As I know soundcloud team is using StackOverflow as support for their developers.

I have simple question with example about search.
In my code I'm using search like this: client.get('/tracks', q=query) where query is "Prinze George - Don't Speak To Me", but in result list "title" key is only "Don't Speak To Me" i.e there is no artist name. When I use soundcloud.com search everything display correct. How can I get full result?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the `user` key to find the `username` key.

Comment: It will help in my case, but doesn't look like correct way. Actually i have different cases for search and sometimes missed data can be found in username as you said, sometimes in permalink, tags or even genre. I wonder how does soundcloud work with it.